# Next js how to define the _app.js and layout.tsx file well

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

I am developing an app locally with next js and I don't know how to differentiate the layout.tsx file from the _app.js file, currently I have very similar content in both.

The main difference between _app.js and Layout.tsx is that _app.js is used for global elements that must be present on all pages, while Layout.tsx is used to define specific layouts for pages or groups of pages. You can combine both options according to the needs of your application to achieve a coherent structure and design.

**_app.js code**

```
// pages/_app.js
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/globals.css';
import Footer from '../components/template/Footer';
import Header from "../components/template/Header";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <>

            <link
                href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans+Condensed:wght@100&family=Lato:ital,wght@0,700;1,400&family=Roboto&display=swap"
                rel="stylesheet"
            />

            <Header />
            <Component {...pageProps} />
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Layout.tsx code

```
import React from 'react';
import Footer from "@/app/components/template/Footer";
import Header from "@/app/components/template/Header";
import './globals.css';

const RootLayout = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <link
                href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans+Condensed:wght@100&family=Lato:ital,wght@0,700;1,400&family=Roboto&display=swap"
                rel="stylesheet"
            />
            <Header />
            <main className="mx-auto lg:max-w-screen-2xl md:max-w-90 md:m-1/4 lg:m-1/4 bg-transparent md:bg-gray-100 lg:bg-gray-100">
                {children}
            </main>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default RootLayout;
```

Example component, Then in all my components I wrap them with the <RootLayout> tag

```
import '../app/styles/globals.css';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import RootLayout from "@/app/layout";
import {Brand} from '@/app/types/types';

const MarcasPage = () => {
    const [brands, setBrands] = useState<Brand[]>([]);
    const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false);
    const baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL;
    const backURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND;


    return (
        <RootLayout>
            <Breadcrumbs items={items}/>
            <div className="lg:ml-20 md:ml-20 lg:mr-20 lg:ml-20 ml-1 mr-1 ">
                <SearchCars />
            </div>
            <div className="py-8 px-2 md:px-10 lg:px-10 md:mx-10 lg:mx-10 grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
                {brands.map((brand) => (
                    <div>
                          ......
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </RootLayout>
    );
};

export default HomePage;
```

So I don't know how I should program this well, what is the best option, how do you recommend doing it?

Search into google and others platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to answer as comment but the character limit is not enough.

**Note:** My answer is based on your given code that has _app.js files. New Nextjs version is different and it has an app folder that handles routes and components, layout.js files that handles layout, page.js files that say "hey, I am a page and need a route".

Let me descriibe the difference between _app.tsx and layout.tsx now:

**_app.tsx**

_app.tsx is for global and consistent elements across all pages. Here you should have elements and logic that apply globally across all pages. This could include your font imports and certain layout elements like headers and footers, provided you want them to appear on every single page without exception.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <>
            <link 
               href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans+Condensed:wght@100&family=Lato:ital,wght@0,700;1,400&family=Roboto&display=swap" 
               rel="stylesheet" 
            />
            <Header />
            <Component {...pageProps} />
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default MyApp;
```

**Layout.tsx**

Layout.tsx should handle layouts that could be specific to a group of pages but not necessarily global. Here you can have a more modular approach.

For example, if you have a set of pages that require a sidebar, you would define that layout here. It's also a good place to define your main content area if it differs between pages or page groups.

```
const RootLayout = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <main className="...">
                {children}
            </main>
        </>
    );
};
export default RootLayout;
```

**Pages**

Your actual page components can then just focus on content and logic, without worrying too much about layout specifics. For example you can wrap them with a rooter like  if they require a page-specific layout.

After all I advice you to use Nextjs latest version and its app route that gives you an architectural vision about these. For example there is a template.js file now and it behaves like a layout with "key" property. That means it will re-render in different pages. That can be helpful for some use cases such as "remembering scroll position for each page that has the same layout"